# Web application wont deploy using Netbeans 8.1 and Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have just re installed Netbeans 8.1 and Tomcat 8 and i want to deploy and run a web application i have created. However once i try to deploy the application or run it i get the following error

C:\Users\Sean\Desktop\Demeter\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 36 seconds)

Also the link above links to the build-impl.xml on this line:

```
  <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Obviously the thing to do next would be the check the server logs as stated, but the thing is the server log window in netbeans is completely blank, so i dont know what to do. Has anyone come across this problem before? Please feel free to give me advice about this issue. Also i have tried going to the manager gui page, but that too displays a blank white page and i have specified the manager-gui role already in the xml file.

Comment: Hello Sean Sheehy , i want to know what is the version of your tomcat is't the portable version or the full version ?

Comment: @mehdizahrane Hi mehdi, from what i can tell this is the full version of Tomcat 8.